# Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I'm trying to get the source code of https://www.americasarmy.com/soldier/1309069

using the following code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{

    ViewBag.htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.americasarmy.com/soldier/1309069");
}
```

Comment: u can see here the error [link](http://imgur.com/a/BD8Yy)

Comment: [Same](http://imgur.com/a/kssdj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it returns 404, the source string will be in the WebException.Response :

```
try
{
    client.DownloadString("https://www.americasarmy.com/soldier/1309069");
}
catch (WebException webex)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(webex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var htmlCode = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @David : Open your F12 tool

Comment: Another reason why you shouldn't use `WebClient` and instead use `HttpClient`!